# SQL Database 'Space Available' - Reaching Max Space on Drive

Tags: sql-server, database

We have a legacy SQL Server in-house that is presently used by a 3rd party to store data on that we are required to keep for a number of years. This SQL Server is unfortunately an old Windows Server 2003 / SQL Server 2005 based server and I have no more room to expand the drives.

The issue that is occurring is that the drive is reaching critical mass to the point where the backup and the subsequent truncation of the transaction logs is what is keeping the db going due to the free space, however this is going to reach a point where this maxes out.

I have backed up several years worth of the data onto an Azure SQL Database and then deleted the relevant rows from the DB, however the DB file remains at a large size.

According to the database properties there is 45929.45 MB of space available, is there anyway I can shrink this DB from its 218912.00 MB size by roughly 30GB so that there is more 'growth' space available on the drive itself (there are OTHER database files located on the same drive).

I've read that shrinking a DB is bad practice due to fragmentation, but I'm getting to the point where with my limited SQL I need to rectify this.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Shrinking regularly can be bad, but a one off for making space after a large delete is probably OK, especially if you re-index afterwards.

Comment: Can you point your backups to a different drive? Network share?

Comment: @WEI_DBA It isn't the backups taking up the space - its the actual DB size.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarification. You can definitely shrink the DB. Look at your Transaction Log files as well. Those can be shrunk daily after T-Log backups. You may want to look at your index space used. If unnecessary indexes have been created they can take up a good amount of space in your data file.